# How to add a seperate HTML file inside the react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to add a separate HTML page to route from an existing create-react-app project

I have tried to load up the html page as a component and render it through the react router. However this ***error*** is shown whenever i try to load up the server.

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> <!doctype html>
| <html>
| <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Here is the render function in ***app.js*** in order to declare the routes:

```
  render(){
    return (
      <Router>
      <Fragment>
        <Navbar />

        <Route exact path= '/' component={ Landing } />

        <section>

          <Switch>

            <Route exact path= '/team' 
            render = { () => <Team teamData = {teamData} />} />
            <Route exact path= '/research' component={ Research } />
            <Route exact path= '/involved' component={ Involved } />
            <Route exact path= '/experiment' component={ experiment } />

            <Route exact path= '/contact'
              render={ () => <Contact env = {this.props.env} /> } />
            {/* <Route exact path = "/visualltm.html"
            render {() => {window.location.href = "visualltm.html"}} /> */}
          </Switch> 

          <Footer />

      </section>

        </Fragment>

      </Router>
```

And here is the seperate HTML file i am trying to load:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        ***Here goes the content***
  </body>
</html>
```

***I expect the html page to be routed *** not but not create a component for it but seems like its just showing the error

Comment: What are you trying to gain from using an HTML file instead of rendering a JSX component?

Comment: Its an seperate experiment working entirely on its own rather than the react dom.

Comment: did you found any solution I also want to do this but have no idea how to do this